# No se renderizan las vistas en una app de django

Tags: python, django, web

Estoy haciendo un curso de django y me encontre la siguiente limitacion, en la creacion de la pagina llamada blog, tenia que hacer un filtro para ver las categorias, pero no se mostraba la pagina, como si no existiera, aunque yo registre la app, y puse en los settings en los dirs la carpeta donde tenia que buscar, probe simplemente intentando renderizar el htlm sin el codigo de las categorias y me seguia sin renderizar nada.

Dejo el codigo de las vistas y parte del arbol de trabajo

Codigo de las vistas:

```
        from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

        from Blog.models import Categorias, post



        def blog(request):
           Po=post.objects.all()
           return render(request,'Blog/Blog',{"Po":Po})

        def prueba(request):
         return render(request,'Blog/Categorias')
```

codigo de las Urls:

```
        from django.urls import path

        from django.conf import settings

        from django.conf.urls.static import static

        from Blog.views import blog, prueba

        urlpatterns = [
            path('', blog, name="Blog"),


            path('Cat',prueba,name='C')
            ]
```

Imagen del arbol de trabajo de la app:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error que me salio era el tipico de page not found, y no tengo ni idea de como solucionarlo
Subire el repositorio de Git hub para ver si eso ayuda mas a encontrar el problema
https://github.com/wredboy2021/Proyecto-Web-Final

Comment: La pagina http://127.0.0.1:8000/ te muestra el blog? O no te muestra ni una ni la otra? Puedes pegar el error que te muestra?

Comment: La pagina me muestra el blog, pero a la hora de intentar llegar a la otra pagina no la renderiza, como si no existiera, aunque ya este registrada en url pathers

Comment: En la carpeta Blog del repositorio tienes el archivo views.py vacio y tampoco tienes el archivo urls.py...

Comment: Ya la info debe de estar en el repositorio, una disculpa, como e estado intentando resolver el problema, ni me tome el tiempo de subir los cambios a Git

Comment: No sé si puede ser esto pero en el view tienes: def prueba(request):
    return render(request, 'Blog/Categorias.html') y tendria que ser def prueba(request):
    return render(request, 'Blog/Categorias'). Asi como en el template Categorias tienes un cierre de div que sobra. En el archivo urls tienes path('C', prueba, name='C'), y tendria que ser path('categoria/', prueba, name='C'), Espero haverte ayudado

Comment: lamentablemente no, anterior mente lo deje de la manera correcta, ya quedandome sin ideas lo puse con el htlm, a ver si por un milagro del cielo funcionaba, pero nada y lo del div si me lo miro, pero de igual forma tengo que seguir buscando el error o porque no renderiza esa vista, y lo del path pues lo mismo, no se si sea la manera que escribo la url, es algo haci, 127.0.0.01:8000/Blog/C, es la forma correcta de escribir la url segun lo que aprendi en el curso que estoy haciendo

Comment: Ahora veo que en el view prueba solo cargas el template pero sin añadir ningun objeto. Prueva a incluir Po=post.objects.all() para ver si como minimo te carga la primera parte del template... Y sino pues ya no se que más decirte :(

Comment: Nada, sinceramente no se que pasa, todo parece estar bien y es como si no existiera la pagina que estoy intentando cargar. Si me podrias ayudar con algo mas, sabes como se llama el termino con el que se hace referencia a esto: /blog/C, para buscarlo mas a fondo y tal vez llegar a una solucion

Comment: Olvide lo que dije, me quiero morir, era un simple / en el url pather al inicio, me respondere a mi mismo, de igual manera gracias por intentar ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

Bueno era una de esas cosas tontas que nos pasan en la programacion

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',blog,name='Blog'),
path('categorias/',prueba)
```

]

este es mi Url pathers cuando todavia no tenia ni idea de que estaba pasando, aclaro que en otras partes del codigo no me daba problemas al dejarlo de esa manera sin el / al principio, pues bien esta es la solucion

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',blog,name='Blog'),
path('/categorias/',prueba)
```

]

Esta va a ser una de las cosas que nunca en mi vida olvidare